# Get a variable from a method called on that variable without using paramaters

Tags: javascript, parameters, monkeypatching

I'm new to javascript and have a question that's probably stupid.

**Context**

`or` is a method that I have written myself for the String class through monkey patching.

**Question**

I want to be able to call the `or` method like this:

```
'dog'.or('cat')
```

The problem is that the `or` method needs to know about the string that it was called on.

Is there anyway to access `'dog'` from inside the `or` method without passing it in as a parameter?

Comment: Could you add the way you monkey patched the String class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it using the `this` keyword. [Read more.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Here is an example:

```
String.prototype.show = function ()
{
    alert(this);
}
"Hello, World!".show();
```

[See it in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/kendfrey/WmACS/)

Comment: Good answer. Note, when not in strict mode 'dog' passed as 'this' to the or method is _not_ the string 'dog', but rather a String object that auto-boxed the string primitive value 'dog' so a call to valueOf might be needed.